# How can open an specific element of html file in modal with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I want to access to a grid from a html file, for select a row. I try to open person page in modal, but i just need to access to grid element from that page.

```
var modalInstance = $modal
                      .open({
                          size: 'lg',
                          templateUrl: 'person/person.html',
                          controller: 'personCtrl',
                          resolve: {}
                       });
```

How can i specify that element to open?

Comment: You have your `resolve: {}` for that, so you can pass to `personCtrl` selected user id, or even person object with all details if you want.